# ufpdf in xampp 1.7.2

Tags: php, pdf, unicode, fpdf

I used [ufpdf](http://acko.net/blog/ufpdf) to generate pdf files with Unicode/UTF-8 in PHP. It works properly in xampp 1.6.7 for windows.

However, I tested it in xampp 1.7.2(window), it doesn't work and I got like that:

"%PDF-1.3 3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x�3R��2�35W(�r Q�w3T06�30PISp     �Z*�[��Y+��..."

Comment: I tried with another one called tcpdf that supports UTF-8/Unicode and now it works in PHP.
http://bit.ly/19lZFR

Answer (score 0):

It seem there is problem in rendering the files to the pdf. I will  suggest you to used the liberies of DOM PDF or html2ps. These are widely used for rendering the PHP files.

I will prefer DOM PDF for your need.

[HTML2PS](http://www.discoverlife.org/ed/tg/html2ps.html)

[dompdf](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/)